# How to reduce mouse pointer shaking?

Tags: software-recommendation, mouse-pointer

The mouse pointer recently starts shaking. Seems there is a hardware problem. Is there any software to remove the pointer shake?

Comment: Since this turned out not to be Ubuntu-related at all, would you consider closing the question?

Comment: Nope. It really happens for an Ubuntu user. Also it can be solved in hardware or software manner. It can solve an Ubuntu user's issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. There was another mouse connected to PC. Seems the vibration came from it. just unplugged and it solved the problem.